# nonegative inverse eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, block-matrices

I need to construct a non-negative matrix with desired eigenvalues. To that end, I came up with a block matrix of the following form:

$$
\mathbf{M} =  \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{b} \\
\mathbf{c^T} & \it{d} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Where matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is free parameter, and vectors $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and scalar $\it{d}$ depend on $\mathbf{A}$ and a set of desired eigenvalues (given as diagonal elements of matrix $\mathbf{\Lambda} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$)

Equation that relates $\mathbf{c}$ to $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is quite complicated and involves an inverse of the solution to a Sylvester equation. Namely

$$
\mathbf{c^T} = \left[\text{diag}(\mathbf{\Lambda}) - \mathbf{1^T}(\text{tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda}-\mathbf{A}) + \sigma)\right]\mathbf{K^{-1}}
$$

where $\mathbf{K}$ is a solution to a following Sylvester equation:

$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{K}-\mathbf{K}\mathbf{\Lambda} = (\mathbf{A}-\sigma\mathbf{I}_n)\mathbf{1} \cdot\mathbf{1^T}
$$

**Questions:**

How to find constraints on parameter $\mathbf{A}$ which will render $\mathbf{M}$ non-negative?

$\mathbf{A}$ itself must be non-negative of course, and $\mathbf{b}$ and $d$ have a straightforward dependence on $\mathbf{A}$, so it's easy. I have no idea, however, what to do with $\mathbf{c}$, because there's this $\mathbf{K^{-1}}$ which I don't have a solution for (only for $\text{vec}(\mathbf{K})$). How could I approach the question analytically? Or is there an efficient numerical way to solve the problem (e.g. given $\mathbf{\Lambda}$, find $A$ that maximizes the smallest element of $M$)?

---

**Details:**

Here's the dependence of $\mathbf{b}$ and $d$ on $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$:

$$
\mathbf{b} = (\sigma \mathbf{I}_n - \mathbf{A})\mathbf{1}
$$

$$
d = \text{tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda} - \mathbf{A}) + \sigma
$$

and a vectorized solution for $\mathbf{K}$

$$
\text{vec}(\mathbf{K}) = (\mathbf{I}_n \otimes\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{\Lambda} \otimes \mathbf{I}_n)^{-1}(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{b})
$$

Given these relations, the resulting matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is equivalent to
$$
\mathbf{M} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{b} \\
\mathbf{c^T} & \it{d} \\
\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{K} & \mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1^T} & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{\Lambda} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \sigma \\
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{K} & \mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1^T} & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}^{-1}
$$

$\mathbf{\Lambda}$ need not be diagonal, but its eigenvalues must be chosen as an input argument.

---

**UPD**: ok, sorry for a confusing question. I'll try to clear things up with a 2 $\times$ 2 special case. It can be shown that a 2 $\times$ 2 matrix of the form

$$
\mathbf{M} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
a & \sigma - a \\
a - \lambda & \sigma - (a - \lambda) \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

has equal row-sum ($\sigma$) and a set of eigenvalues $\{\lambda, \sigma\}$ for any arbitrary choice of $a$. Now, because all equations are scalar, it is easy to find constraints on $a$ and $\lambda$ that will result in a non-negative $\mathbf{M}$ by solving a simple system of inequalities. The result is, for $\mathbf{M}$ to be non-negative

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
0 \le & a \le \sigma\\
\lambda \le & a \le \lambda + \sigma \\
-\sigma < &\lambda < \sigma \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

The original question is an attempt to generalize this problem to $(n+1)\times(n+1)$, where $a$ becomes $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and so forth. You can see that equations for $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ and $d$ in the first section of the post collapse to the scalar equations for entries of $\mathbf{M}$ here, when $n$ is set to 1.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not able to read because everything seems so heavy in there. Don't get me wrong ; I know linear algebra very well. But this is an heavy presentation and I don't 'understand' what you're trying to do, I just see a bunch of equations you want to solve.

Comment: So, basically I wanna construct a non-negative matrix with desired eigenvalues. Non-negative here means that all the entries are non-negative. There is another constraint: the matrix has to have equal row-sum, but that's equivalent to requiring the matrix to have one of the eigenvectors = 1, with eigenvalue = sigma, hence the particular form of the very last equation. There's a subspace of such matrices, defined by the directions of the rest of the eigenvectors (K). I decided to parametrize them by the upper left block of the matrix in question, and the very first equation relates one to other

Comment: Plz, let me know if there's anything else unclear. I just didn't want to have too much text there, which was a mistake, apparently

Comment: Added 2x2 example in attempt to clear things up

Comment: Have you heard of the [Perron-Frobenius theorem][1] for positive square matrices? I think that may hep you constrain your matrices. For instance if I have understood it correctly only one of the eigenvectors can have all positive entries and it's eigenvalue is the largest in the absolute sense.


  [1]: http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/685fa12/sternberg_perron_frobenius.pdf

Comment: @GrahamHesketh, the theorem looks like a big deal and definitely needs a closer look, thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't do the $c^T = [\text{stuff}]K^{-1}$ solve? Eg., in matlab c = ([stuff]/reshape(K,n,n))'; (or using an iterative solver like gmres). Is it a really bad matrix?

Comment: @NickAlger Oh, no no, numerically it works perfectly, that is: give me reasonably well behaved $A$ and $L$ and I'll build $M$ numerically, using results above. BUT then, $M$ is not guaranteed to be positive. The question is, what $A$ am I allowed to use with given $\Lambda$, s.t. the matrix $M$ is positive (elementwise). For that, I need some tractable analytic solution for $c^T$, so that I can find constraints on $A$. In the current form, I don't know how to do this, because of the nasty inverse.

Comment: Really interesting problem. I hope you will post the results if you figure it out. Also, I think you can consider only diagonal $A$ without loss of generality - see my "answer" below.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I have completely misunderstood you, but it seems in the comments you are after a matrix (call it $\mathbf{M}$)  that has:

- some desired eigenvalues
- equal row sum.

If they are the only constraints, consider a square arbitrary diagonalizable matrix, $\mathbf{M}$:
$$\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{S}^{-1}.$$
The column vectors of $\mathbf{S}$ are the right eigenvectors of matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{M}$. To construct your $\mathbf{M}$ you would then simply fill $\mathbf{D}$ with the desired eigenvalues and then, to insure that the row sums of $\mathbf{M}$ are equal, as you noted, you make every element of one of the column vectors of $\mathbf{S}$ (call it $E_1$) to be equal to $1$, then fill up the rest of $\mathbf{S}$ however you please so long as $\text{det}[\mathbf{S}]\ne0$, then finally calculate the inverse $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ and you have your $\mathbf{M}$. The row sum would then be equal to the eigenvalue (call it $e_1$) corresponding to $E_1$ as can be seen by noting that the right hand side of: $$e_1E_1=\mathbf{M}E_1$$ gives a column vector containing the row sums and the left hand side is a column vector full of eigenvalue $e_1$.

**Example:**

Take $\mathbf{D}$ as the matrix containing your given set of eigenvalues on the diagonal:
$$\mathbf{D}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \sigma&0&0\\ 0&1&0
\\ 0&0&2\end {array} \right], $$
then construct $\mathbf{S}$:
$$\mathbf{S}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&2&3\\ 1&3&4
\\ 1&4&6\end {array} \right],$$ 
then find the inverse:
$$ \mathbf{S}^{-1}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2&0&-1\\ -2&3&-1
\\ 1&-2&1\end {array} \right], 
$$
then build $\mathbf{M}$:
$$ \mathbf{M}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{S}^{-1}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2\,\sigma+2&-6&-\sigma+4
\\ 2\,\sigma+2&-7&-\sigma+5\\ 2\
\sigma+4&-12&-\sigma+8\end {array} \right], 
$$
$$\text{row sum}=\sigma.$$

I'm sure this is not what you're asking for as I ignored the Sylvestre equation e.t.c, but I'll post it just in case. I'll delete it when you highlight my ignorance...

Comment: Thanks. You see, N-1 columns of S are free, i.e. they can be chosen arbitrary without violating the constraints on M, as long as D is untouched. Now, the individual elements of M do depend on the particular choice of S. The last equation in my post relates blocks of M to respective blocks of S and D (using your naming convention). It can be shown that one needs only (N-1)x(N-1) block of S (that would be matrix K) as a parameter, to define all possible M's with given eigenvalues (because the length of ev's doesn't matter), hence the last row of S is also = 1 in my equation.

Comment: the QUESTION is: which K (or, ultimately, A) should I choose, such that all entries of M are positive, without violating the aforementioned constraints. PS: no need to delete the answer of course

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I'm with you now. Somehow I read "all the entries are non-negative" as all the eigenvalues are non-negative :( Must have been tired... With that said, your question is which $\mathbf{K}$ give all entries of $\mathbf{M}>0$? Sure, got it. But, based on the (borderline irrelevant) things in my answer any $\mathbf{K}$ will not obstruct the eigenvalues or the row sum provided $\text{det}[\mathbf{S}]\ne0$ right? Provided $\Lambda$ is diagonal maybe...

Comment: Exactly, K is a free parameter which affects entries of M, but not its eigenvalues (including sigma). Therefore, all blocks of M (A, b, c, d) depend upon K. What I did, is I derived the expression for that dependence and then inverted it to use A as a free parameter instead, and derived expressions for the rest of M (blocks b,c and d) on A. I've added a 2x2 example to the end of the question. Have a look, I think it should clarify things

Comment: Concerning $\mathbf{\Lambda}$, actually it need not be diagonal for the block-equation for M to hold. It should only have eigenvalues same as the ones you want M to have, except sigma of course

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather a simplification of the problem that can't be fit into the comments.

Without loss of generality, one can assume that $A$ is diagonal. Why? Well suppose $A = U \Sigma U^T$ is the (full) SVD of $A$. Then we can convert the problem to a diagonal one via the similarity transformation,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
U^T \\ & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\ c^T & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U \\ & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & U^T b \\ c^T U & d
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since similarity transforms preserve eigenvalues and since $b$ and $c$ could be anything, we might as well instead compute the necessary $f,g$ in
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & f \\ g^T & d
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks. But, doesn't it undermine the  positivity constrain?

Comment: Oh hmm didn't catch that constraint.